# How to us a Printer in Lua and cups

Tags: linux, printing, lua, raspberry-pi, cups

My configuration:

- System: Linux
- Hardware: Raspberry Pi2
- Language: Lua 5.1

I want to print some text out of a lua script. CUPS is running, printer is working. But I don't know how to send some data to the printer. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a pipe to `lpr` and write to it:

```
out = assert(io.popen("lpr","w"))
out:write("Hello\n")
out:close()
```

If `lpr` does not work, try `lp`.